# How do I run gvim within the same shell window?

Tags: mac, shell, vim, gvim

I'm running gvim on my mac from /usr/local/bin.  If I invoke it from a terminal window it opens it up in a new window.  I'd like to get it to just run in the same window I'm already using.  How do I do that?  I realize this is probably a really dumb question but I'm a big time mac noob.

Comment: You don't.  you use `vim` or `vi`.

Comment: gvim doesn't run in a terminal, it needs its own graphical window. As the others said, use vim instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'gvim' is the graphical version of vim. Try /usr/local/bin/vim instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Mac, but I'm using `gVim` on my Windows PC (I have it loaded on a USB) and I can enter the terminal mode by running the core exe within the file tree.

(Keep in mind: I am using a version of `gVim` downloaded from PortableApps.com.)

When you go into your gVimPortable folder you should see:

```
App (folder)
Data (folder)
Other (folder)
gVimPortable.exe
help.html
```

clicking `gVimPortable` will give you a GUI version like normal, but instead try this:

```
App
 vim
  vim74
```

And run `vim.exe` NOT `gVim.exe`.

To open it from within a already opened command window just type the full path to the file and include `vim.exe` onto the end of it.

I hopes this helps you on mac!

Comment: +1 Although there is another, straightforward answer for Mac, this answer will be useful for Windows users with similar problem.